# PyInstaller Executable Problem: Executable runs on my own Mac but not on others' Mac

Tags: python

I'm currently making a Pokemon-inspired command line game written in Python and SQL. I have created a 1 file UNIX executable using PyInstaller, and my game runs fine on my own computer (Mac). I have also made a zip file and shared it on Google Drive for others to play. However, when other people play it on their Mac, they get the error

```
Error loading Python lib '/var/folders/... /Python :dlopen :dlopen(/var/folders/.../Python, 10): no suitable image found. Did find: /var/folders/... /Python: code signature invalid for /var/folders/... /Python' /var/folders/... /Python: stat () failed with errno=3
```

Can someone pls help me?

BTW, here is the link to the zip file, in case you want to debug

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nIKdQMqKdasXX1R5BIV8HCuCc7EE9FBf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Pls don't make the answer too technical, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: is there any prerequisites to run the game? it seems like it can't find the python path

Comment: I thought PyInstaller packages all prerequisites into the executable though, so others don't need to install them anymore

Comment: List the UNIX file you've created.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by list?